# Show if the maximum of product $xy$ predict the maximum of $x \ln(1+by)$ using calculus?

Tags: calculus

My coffee is broken and I can't do math today. In [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/37900/12102) I've derived an expression of the form

$$F=x \ln(1+by)$$

and its approximation for $by<<1$

$$G =xby$$

That $G$ is always larger for a larger product $xy$ is trivial, but how do I demonstrate if when comparing two pairs of real positive $(x, y)$ the pair with the larger product $xy$ either 1) will also be or 2) might not always be the pair with the larger $F$?

I started by writing the metric $M=xy$ and then writing

$$F = \frac{M}{y} \ln(1+by) $$

and then I wrote

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial M} = \ ... $$

but that's not helping and I'm not sure where to go next. I know this is embarrassingly trivial, but I'm stuck.

*addressing [@parsiad's comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3311955/show-if-the-maximum-of-product-xy-predict-the-maximum-of-x-ln1by#comment6814067_3311955):* Selection of the calculus tag and the partial derivative above are meant to indicate that I'm looking for a *calculus-based solution* if one exists. While searching for a numerical counterexample might be useful to show it is not always true, that might become unwieldily in some cases and failure to find one might be inconclusive in others.

Comment: What is $F^\prime$? The derivative of $F$ with respect to ____?

Comment: @parsiad no, I stated "and it's approximation for $by<<1$ ... $F'=$..." But I'll change it to $G$, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to look for a counterexample numerically?

Comment: @parsiad that won't help me understand how to use mathematics here. Changed "Does" to "Show" in the title...

Comment: If you want to disprove a statement, a counterexample is a fine way to do it. That *is* mathematics. "Show" doesn't imply that a counterexample is not acceptable.

Comment: @parsiad suppose the next time I need to address this type of problem that searching for a counterexample would be much more complex, possibly requiring a computer which I might not have on hand. I used the `calculus` tag in hopes that there is some way to address this using calculus. If there isn't then a different solution would have to do.

Answer (score 1):

Note that as $x,y$ get large, $F$ increases rapidly with $x$, not so much with $y$.  You should be able to find a pair with $xy$ larger but $F$ smaller by making $y$ larger and $x$ smaller.  This violates the $by \ll 1$ condition.

Just to take an example, let $b=10^6$.  If $x=1000, y=1, xy=1000, F=1000\ln(10^6+1)\approx 13815$,
while if
$x=1, y=10^6, xy=1,000,000, F=\ln(10^{12}+1)\approx 27.63$

If you insist on calculus, you can take the derivative of $F$ with respect to $y$, getting $$\frac {\partial F}{\partial y}=\frac{M(1+by)^{-1}-M\log(1+by)}{y^2}$$
and note that it is not zero, so for fixed $M$ the value of $F$ will change with $y$.  Using continuity you can then find a counterexample.

Comment: thanks, but as explained in the question and in comments below it I'm looking for a way to show this using calculus.

Comment: I think the right intuitive approach is the one in my first sentence.  Just recognize that logarithms grow slowly with the argument.  That is the right way to get a feel for the function.  An approximation that depends on $by \ll 1$ is not useful when we are talking about large $y$.